# Drupal 7 - Programatically add textfield on specific taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Below code adding the textfield on all taxonomy add  form, but i want to add text field specific taxonomy " color "

```
  if(!db_table_exists('field_data_field_moi_uc_oid')){
      $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_moi_uc_oid',
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => t('Relates to option')
      );
      field_create_field($field);
    }
    // Attach the field to our taxonomy entity
    $instance = array(
      'field_name' => 'field_moi_uc_oid',
      'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      'bundle' => 'variant',
      'label' => t('Relates to option'),
      'description' => t('This is the description'),
      'required' => true,
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',
        'settings'=> array(
          'max_width'=>80,
        )
      ),
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
```

Comment: you are currently applying the field to the taxonomy terms on the 'variant' taxonomy/bundle. 'variant' is your taxonomy. Where does color come into it?

Comment: variant is vocabulary, this vocabullary contain two taxonomy, color and size. different fields need to create for these two taxonomy

Comment: I am confused with your set up then. As far as I know, taxonomy terms are added to vocabularies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomies in Drupal are grouped in vocabularies. it can be (Colors, Tags ...etc)
Then each Taxonomy vocabulary has terms (the actual data).

The code above is creating a field into a SINGLE vocabulary called variant

```
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_moi_uc_oid',
  'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
  // This is the vocabulary
  'bundle' => 'variant',
  'label' => t('Relates to option'),
  'description' => t('This is the description'),
  'required' => true,
  'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'text_textfield',
    'settings'=> array(
      'max_width'=>80,
    )
  ),
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

To make this code snippet create a field instead for the color vocabulary then just change this line

```
  'bundle' => 'color',
```

remember, I can only see answer based on what you said :)